# Connect Drupal to external data base

Tags: views, database

Is there a specific module or a definied mechanism to connect a given external data base to a view?

---

#### settings.php

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => array (
    'default' => array (
      'database' => 'd3js',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),

  'NewDataBase' => array (
    'default' => array (
      'database' => 'NewDataBase',
      'username' => 'username',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => '131.188.76.40',
      'port' => '3306',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ), 
);
```

This is the module that is related to the view.

```
 /**
  * @file
  * D3 views module file.
  */

 /**
  * Implements hook_views_api().
  */
  function d3_views_views_api() {
   return array(
   'api' => 3,
   'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'd3_views') . '/views',
  );
 }

 /**
  * Implements hook_theme().
  */
function d3_views_theme() {

   return array(
   'views_ui_style_d3_options_form' => array(
   'render element' => 'form',
   ),
 );

}

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_views_ui_style_d3_options_form().
 */
 function d3_preprocess_views_ui_style_d3_options_form(&$vars) {
   drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'd3_views') . '/css/views_ui_style_options_form.css');
 }

/**
 * Theme the form for the table style plugin.
 */
 //declarition of the variables related to form (tree)
 function theme_views_ui_style_d3_options_form($variables) {
 $form = $variables['form'];

 $output = drupal_render($form['library']);

 $header = array(
 t('Field'),
 t('Display'),
 t('Aggregation'),
 t('Data type'),
);
 $rows = array();
 foreach (element_children($form['columns']) as $id) {
 $row = array();
 $row[] = drupal_render($form['columns'][$id]['name']);
 $row[] = drupal_render($form['columns'][$id]['display']);
 $row[] = drupal_render($form['columns'][$id]['aggregate']);
 $row[] = drupal_render($form['columns'][$id]['type']);

 $rows[] = $row;
 }

 $output .= '<fieldset><legend>Data</legend>' . theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows)) . '</fieldset>';

 $output .= drupal_render_children($form);
 return $output;
}
```

This module also has and I didn't know exactly where to connect to the database.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the following configuration in your settings.php file

```
$databases = array();
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  // Drupal's default credentials here.
);
$databases['my_other_db']['default'] = array(
  // Your secondary database's credentials here.
);
```

Refer to settings.php for the array options.

Now if you are using a custom module you can use the following in  your module to switch between the 2 db's

```
// Use the database we set up earlier
db_set_active('my_other_db');
```

and if you want to move back to the default db

```
// Go back to the default database,
// Remember to go back to the drupal default version or drupal will not be able to access its data
db_set_active();
```

Also refer to https://drupal.org/node/18429 for more information.

There is one more of doing it if you do not want to do the db_set_Active() all the time.

So you define the connection in your settings.php like in the first step. Then in the module you can directly do the following

```
$query = Database::getConnection('default', 'my_other_db')
           ->select('source_table', 'st')
...
```

Comment: I want that the module view extract data from the external data base so I added the database to the settings.php file and then in the view module I added:first line: db_set_active('my_other_db');

and the last line in the module view.module:
db_set_active(); but this is not working

Comment: @LearningHowToBeAGoodProgrammer can you paste the config from your settings.php and your module code. Without looking at the code I cannot comment.